# sqlQuery with Query String in Azure Functions 2.x?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I have an app in Function 1.x that gets objId from query strings, queries CosmosDb (input binding) and then does rest of job. However, I'm migrating it into v2, and it doesn't work as it used to: it queries db only if the objId is provided in route template, but not if objId is provided as query string (in v1, it works even if it's provided as query string). Even though my function.json is almost same. Can you tell me what's wrong and how can I make that input binding to do the sql query by means of query string?

Following is content of my function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "obj",
      "databaseName": "mydb",
      "collectionName": "objects",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c where c.id = {objId}",
      "connectionStringSetting": "mydbstring",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

And following is my function code

```
const client = new CosmosClient({
  endpoint: endpoint,
  auth: {
    masterKey: masterKey
  }
});

module.exports = async function (context, req, obj) {
}
```

And following is content of my proxies.json:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
    "proxies": {
        "Set Object state Id Proxy": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/obj/{objId}/state",
                "methods": [
                    "GET"
                ]
            },
            "backendUri": "http://localhost:7071/api/setobjstate?objId={objId}"

        }
}
```

It works this way:

```
http://localhost:7071/games/bbbbb
```

But how can I make it work this way?

```
http://localhost:7071/games?objId=bbbbbbbbb
```

Comment: In my test without proxy, `"sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c where c.id = {objId}"` and `"Id": "{Query.id}"` both work well.  The two function urls seem related a proxy, different from the one you list, right? If so could you share that proxy as well?

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs , it seems that query values, unlike route data, cannot be passed to sql query.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#http-trigger-get-multiple-docs-using-sqlquery-c

From the above link :
"HTTP trigger, look up ID from route data, using SqlQuery (C#)
The following example shows a C# function that retrieves a single document. The function is triggered by an HTTP request that uses route data to specify the ID to look up. That ID is used to retrieve a ToDoItem document from the specified database and collection

The example shows how to use a binding expression in the SqlQuery parameter. **You can pass route data to the SqlQuery parameter as shown, but currently you can't pass query string values.** "

= = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =  = = = = = = = = = = =

However if you only need to retrieve a document by Id, you could it seems , in your function.json 
replace "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM c where c.id = {objId}" with 
"Id": "{Query.id}"

Comment: The link does not show any document that specifies it cannot be used. The answer talks about C#, but the question is about Javascript/NodeJs function.